# What is the difference between these three ways of changing an element in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below please uncomment exactly one line with a hash. Do this for all three possible ways/cases and notice the following:

- All cases seem to imply that elements in the original dataframe are changed
- In my opinion they accomplish the same (except for the fact that the selected elements differ in the three cases - but thats not my point)
- Yet: Only in case 2 I get a warning: "SettingWithCopyWarning:
  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

So here is my question: Why is case 2 particularly bad in comparison to case 1 and 3? I don't understand why I get a warning. More specifically: Even if I accept the rationale behind the warning, I don't understand why it is not issued in the other cases. Can someone explain?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6]})

# subset = df["foo"]  # case 1
# subset = df.loc[0:1,:] # case 2
# subset = df.loc[0,:] # case 3

subset.iloc[0] = 100
```

Comment: Case 2 actually produces a `DataFrame`, rather than a `Series` value.

Comment: I understand this. But why is this a major problem and justifies a warning - in comparison to the other cases?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly the warning is generated, but it seems like case 2 produces a "thinner" wrapper around the contents of the dataframe, facilitating the warning.

Comment: Depends upon how you receive the results of a get operation. It is ambiguos and can return both a view or a copy. 
I'll add few links for you to get a rough overview of  this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas
A good article:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/11/3-ways-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/

Now, a simple escape here is to define that you want to work with a copy of df and not the view, by defining subset = df.loc[0:1,:].copy()

Comment: Case1 and case3 returns a series while case2 returns a dataframe. This warning is associated with dataframes specifically. 
For optimization purpose, pandas returns the results of a get() operation ambigously either as a view or a copy. Modification of an ambigous copy can cause this warning.

Comment: Forgive me for saying: But I don't get any insights when saying that case 2 returns a dataframe and other cases return a series. I want to have a logical reason as to why case 2 is more "dangerous".

Comment: This is likely related to the very next [pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78008300/9473764); see the comment by @Floriancitt about the difference between integers and strings in views and copies. If you change `df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": ['1', '2', '3'], "bar": [4, 5, 6]})` i.e. `foo` is now strings, you'll find all three methods give you a warning.